# Struct length of long depending on byte order?

Tags: python, python-2.7, struct

I want to use `struct.unpack()` to get a long value from a byte string in Python 2.7, but I found some strange behaviour and I would like to know if this is a bug or not, and also, what I can do to get around it.

What happens is the following:

```
import struct
>>> struct.unpack("L","")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8
```

This is the expected behaviour. It wants an 8-byte string to extract the 8-byte long value.

Now I change the byte order to network byte order and I get the following:

```
>>> struct.unpack("!L","")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

Suddenly it only wants 4 bytes for the 8-byte long value.

What is up with that, and what can I do to get around this?

Comment: I get 4 in the error message for the first part... python 2.7.8 used here.

Comment: That's strange... Isn't long in Python specified as 64-bit/8-byte integer?

Comment: long in python has no finite size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `struct` is using your machine's native `long` size in the first case, and `struct`'s "standard" `long` size in the second.

In the first example, you don't specify a [byte-order, size, and alignment specifier](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) (one of `@=<>!`) so `struct` assumes `'@'`, which uses your machine's native values, namely your machine's native `long` size. In order to be consistent across platforms, [`struct` defines standard sizes for each type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters), which may differ from your machine's native sizes. Every specifier except for `'@'` uses these standard sizes.

So, in the case of `long`, `struct`'s standard is 4 bytes, which is why `'!L'` (or any `'[=<>!]L'` expects 4 bytes. However, your machine's native `long` is apparently 8 bytes, which is why `'@L'` or `'L'` expects 8. If you want to use your machine's native byte-order, but still be compatible with `struct`'s standard sizes, I would recommend that you specify all formats with `'='`, instead of letting Python default it to `'@'`.

---

You can check the size expectation with `struct.calcsize`, i.e.:

```
>>> struct.calcsize('@L'), struct.calcsize('=L')
```

(this returns `(4, 4)` on my 64-bit Windows 10 machine, but `(8, 4)` on my 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 machine.)

You can also directly check your machine's type size by compiling a `C` script to check the value of `sizeof(long)`, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%li",sizeof(long));
    return 0;
}
```

I followed [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx) to compile the `C` script on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer to an old question! You explained that very well. This is just another one of these "Python is stupid" moments...

Comment: No problem, I stumbled upon this question while researching something similar. I honestly wouldn't call it a "stupid python" moment, but rather an exception to the Principle of Least Astonishment. That is, I would prefer 2 things to be different: for `'='` to be the default; and for `long` to be larger than `int` in the standard. But I'm only speaking from my own experience, and I am by no means an expert! I'm sure the `struct` designers had good reasons to make it this way.